# Adding button to automatic slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created an automatic slideshow and would like to add buttons down the bottom as a method of changing the slides as well as having them change automatically. With the code I have they don't do anything. Any suggestions as to how I can make them do something either through javascript or normal html/css? Also how would I make the images slide across the screen instead of fading?

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var paused = false

setInterval(function() {
    if (paused == false) { 
        $('#slideshow > div:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#slideshow');
    };
},  2000);
});
```

css:

```
.hidden {
display: none;
}

.container {
width: 100%;
height: 85vh;
overflow: hidden;
}

.container > div {
display: inline-block;
}

#slideshow {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 85vh;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
overflow: hidden;
}

#slideshow > div {
position: absolute;
top: 0; 
left: 0; 
right: 0; 
bottom: 0; 
}

#slideshow img {
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
}

.slidershow{
width: 100%;
height: 85vh;
overflow: hidden;
}

.middle{
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.navigation{
position: absolute;
bottom: 20px;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
display: flex;
}

.bar{
width: 50px;
height: 10px;
border: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
margin: 6px;
cursor: pointer;
transition: 0.4s;
}

.bar:hover{
background: #f1f1f1;
}

input[name="r"]{
position: absolute;
visibility: hidden;
}

#r1:checked ~ .s1{
margin-left: 0;
}

#r2:checked ~ .s1{
margin-left: -20%;
}

#r3:checked ~ .s1{
margin-left: -40%;
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head

<body>
    <div class="slidershow middle">
        <div id="slideshow">
            <input type="button" name="r" id="r1" checked>
            <input type="button" name="r" id="r2">
            <input type="button" name="r" id="r3">
            <div>
                <img src="Images/slideshow/roof 1.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="hidden">
                <img src="Images/slideshow/roof 2.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="hidden">
                <img src="Images/slideshow/roof 3.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="navigation">
            <label for="r1" class="bar"></label>
            <label for="r2" class="bar"></label>
            <label for="r3" class="bar"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this one, there are some many good reference that you can make and maybe use those script library as a reference. Or maybe apply it to your code, that way you can lessen your time in developing.

Here are some good examples for `javascript` or `jquery` sliders.

[Skitter Slideshow](https://skitter-slider.net/)

[Rslides](http://responsiveslides.com/)

[Owl Carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/)